# Iterate map and update value in elixir?

Tags: elixir

I have a map/struct data:

```
%{foo: "102", zoo: "103", bar: "104"}
```

I want to iterate the map and update the value to be integer, how should I do it?

```
result = %{foo: 102, zoo: 103, bar: 104}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say that your map is defined as `my_map`:

```
Enum.into(Enum.map(my_map, fn ({key, value}) -> {key, String.to_integer(value)} end), %{})
```

This iterates over the map, remapping its values to Integers, then converting the resulting list of tuples into a proper `Map`.
Note that this returns a new `Map` as the structures are immutable.

Comment: Is the result not a map?

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Also, with [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#for/1) list comprehension:

```rb
for {k, v} <- %{foo: "102", zoo: "103", bar: "104"},
  into: %{},
  do: {k, String.to_integer(v)}
#⇒ %{bar: 104, foo: 102, zoo: 103}
```

---

Or, directly with [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html?#reduce/3).

```rb
Enum.reduce(
  %{foo: "102", zoo: "103", bar: "104"},
  %{},
  fn {k, v}, acc ->
    Map.put(acc, k, String.to_integer(v))
  end
)
#⇒ %{bar: 104, foo: 102, zoo: 103}
```

Comment: That's honestly neater than my answer

Comment: @MilanVelebit that’s not a matter of being neater; I prefer list comprehensions whenever possible because they provide a deadly easy way to filter inplace.

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this using `Map.new`. It is simpler and self descriptive.

```
map = %{foo: "102", zoo: "103", bar: "104"}
Map.new(map, fn {key, value} -> {key, String.to_integer(value)} end)

# %{bar: 104, foo: 102, zoo: 103}
```